# Update AppSync Schema from s3 template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync

I am using cloud-formation to create an AppSync schema.

I have used an S3 file as schema definition for my AppSync API. Now the problem is if I update the s3 file, APpSync  would not update automatically.

When I deploy my cloudformation template, even then cloudformation does not do anything as it does not find the template changed and hence AppSync schema is not updated. I know I can just put the schema in cloudformation template, but that is not very readable and I cannot use IDE plugins to verify syntax of the schema.

Can someone please suggest any suggestion on how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

AWS AppSync does not currently support syncing your APIs with your S3 resources. If you create AppSync resources using CloudFormation, any updates to AppSync should ideally be done through stack updates. We recently launched [Amplify Console](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/console/), to address the best practices around CI/CD of your cloud resources. Amplify Console connects to your Git repository, and does automated builds based on the commits to the connected branch.

You can create your AppSync API using [Amplify GraphQL Transform](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#graphql-transform), so Amplify Console can seamlessly integrate with your project for automating resource creation.

We are working on various efforts to simplify the developer experience, and I'll be glad to take up your use case with the team and get more thoughts on this one.

Comment: Presumably he's triggering a stack update when he deploys his CF templates and still it's not picking up the updated schema. I'm having the same issue